# Binding to the whole data item in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I'm using XAML data binding for a `ListBox` whose `ItemSource` is set to a list of `TypeA` object.  One UI element in the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox` is bound to a property of `TypeA` as follows:

```
Source="{Binding PropertyName, Converter={StaticResource customConverter}}"
```

Now, instead of binding to a specific property, I want the UI element to be bound to the whole `TypeA` instance so that the custom converter can compute value from multiple properties.  The question is: which binding expression I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Youn include no path at all to do that:-

```
 Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource customConverter}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this:

```
Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource customConverter}}"
```

Comment: Both your & Anthony's approach work.  +1 for both.  Since Anthony was first, I accepted his answer.  Thank you.